# AngularJS application config "Uncaught object" error (ngRoute)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url-routing

I have this simple page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head >
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')>

        <script src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='bower_components/angular/angular.js'></script>
        <script src='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/application.js'></script>

        <title>Bets Application</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app='betsApp' ng-controller='betsAppCtrl'>
        <h1>BetsApp</h1>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the `aplication.js` file:

```
var betsApp = angular.module('betsApp', []);

betsApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl:'pages/login.html'});
});

betsApp.controller('betsAppCtrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.email = "";
});
```

and here is the `login.html`:

```
<div>
    <input type='text' ng-model='password' value={{password}}>
</div>
```

When running I am getting this error in console:

```
Uncaught object angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:3809
forEach angular.js:323
loadModules angular.js:3775
createInjector angular.js:3715
doBootstrap angular.js:1379
bootstrap angular.js:1394
angularInit angular.js:1307
(anonymous function) angular.js:21459
n.Callbacks.j jquery.js:3073
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith jquery.js:3185
n.extend.ready jquery.js:3391
```

the code never gets to this lines:

```
$locationProvider.html5mode(true);
$routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl:'pages/login.html'});
```

What have I done wrong?

**Update:**
here is some message I am getting from debugging angular:

```
Line 78, Column 1

Pause On Caught Exceptions

Watch Expressions
Platform: <not available>
data.data: <not available>
Call StackAsync
angular.js:78
(anonymous function)
angular.js:3809
(anonymous function)
angular.js:323
forEach
angular.js:3775
loadModules
angular.js:3715
createInjector
angular.js:1379
doBootstrap
angular.js:1394
bootstrap
angular.js:1307
angularInit
angular.js:21459
(anonymous function)
jquery.js:3073
n.Callbacks.j
jquery.js:3185
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith
jquery.js:3391
n.extend.ready
jquery.js:3407
I
Paused on a JavaScript breakpoint.
Scope Variables
Local
arguments: Arguments[4]
code: "modulerr"
i: 4
message: "[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module betsApp due to:↵Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider↵http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider↵    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12↵    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3705:19↵    at getService (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)↵    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3859:13)↵    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3788:37↵    at Array.forEach (native)↵    at forEach (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11)↵    at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3775:5)↵    at createInjector (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715:11)↵    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1379:20)↵http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=betsApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24routeProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A78%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3705%3A19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3832%3A39)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3859%3A13)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3788%3A37%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A323%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3775%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3715%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1379%3A20)"
prefix: "[$injector:modulerr] "
stringify: function (obj) {
template: "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:↵{1}"
templateArgs: Arguments[4]
this: undefined
Closure
Closure
Window
Global
Breakpoints
angular.js:78
Error(message);
application.js:4
.html5mode(true);
application.js:5
.when('/login', {templateUrl:'pages/login.html'});
DOM Breakpoints
XHR Breakpoints
Event Listener Breakpoints
Workers
"[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module betsApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3705:19
    at getService (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3859:13)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3788:37
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3775:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1379:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=betsApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24routeProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A78%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3705%3A19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3832%3A39)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3859%3A13)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3788%3A37%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A323%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3775%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3715%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1379%3A20)"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you should place `ng-app` on `<html>` element. Maybe you should try to do it on `<body>`

Comment: I removed it and will fix the question. but still the same problem.

Comment: Would be nice if this error threw a little more clue! This may be a good use case to include zone.js for some granular snoopage ;)
https://github.com/angular/zone.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In v1.2+, **[`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)** is a separate module and should be loaded independently (and also declared as a dependency of your main module).

```
<script src='bower_components/angular/angular.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/angular/angular-route.js'></script>

var betsApp = angular.module('betsApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

---

<sub>If you are using bower, you can download the `ngRoute` module with the following command:

`bower install angular-route`</sub>

Comment: Thanks. now there is no error, but the login.html file not loaded to ng-view

Comment: Make sure `login.html` is inside a directory named `pages`. Also, where do you set the path to `/login` ? I don't see a link or something. If you want to navigate there by default, alter your config function like this: `... $routeProvider.when('/login', {...}).otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});`

Comment: the login.html is in the pages folder (I can access it if I am writing `http://localhost:8000/pages/login.html`). I am using the browser url to navigate to the login page, like this: `http://localhost:8000/login`

Comment: have you set up your server to support html5mode ? There needs to be configured. I suggest you try that with html5mode turned off and see if that is the issue. (Note: with html5mode turned off, you need to navigate to `http://localhost:8000/#/login`.)

Comment: changed it to `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

RouteProvider is now in a separate module from the core Angular distribution.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.

Since it looks like you're using bower, I would do a

```
bower install angular-route
```

which will download the requisite `.js` file and place it in the bower_components directory. Modify the HTML to include this script.  Then, the first line line in your application.js file should read:

```
var betsApp = angular.module('betsApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure your Module and ng-app are equals

```
angular.module('foo', ['ngRoute']);

<html ng-app="foo">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add angular-route module!

Comment: Thanks. now there is no error, but the login.html file not loaded to ng-view