# Routing error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

What's wrong with this AngularJS configuration code?

```
 (function () {
        var ip = 'x.x.x.x';

        var app = angular.module('cmal', ['controllers', 'directives', 'services', 'ngRoute'])
            .constant("baseUrl", "http://" + ip + ":303/angular")
            .config( function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: "index.html"});
                $routeProvider.when('/users', { templateUrl: "users.html"});
                $routeProvider.otherwise({template: "Sorry, the page you are trying to reach doesn't exist."});
            });
    })();
```

EDIT: it's not the slash error. This still doesn't work for me and all i get in the console is "Uncaught object"

EDIT 2: Well i didn't realize you needed to import another js script for routing. But so now that I have done that, I get no error, but none of the routes work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? First glance indicates you're missing a / between the port number (303) and path (angular) in your constant definition...

Comment: Double check this bit: `303angular` :)

Comment: Read my edited comment...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not including the separate `angular-route` script.
Take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898348/angular-application-config-uncaught-object-error-ngroute/23898537#23898537)** for more details.

Comment: I realized that and added my "edit 2." This code is still not working. No routes are applied.

Comment: What does your HTML look like ?

Comment: It is something you are not showing us. Better create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem (or if not possible post more code).

Comment: I'm just gonna stick with UIRouter instead...(see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but an alternative solution...I used a separate routing framework.

[UI-Router (a link to the egghead tutorial)](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router)