# How do I resolve the ngRoute issue with Angularjs in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin that uses Angularjs. I've loaded Angularjs and ngRoute locally:

```
wp_enqueue_script('angularjs',plugins_url('/js/angular.min.js', __FILE__ ),array(),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('angularjsroute',plugins_url('/js/angular-route.min.js', __FILE__ ),array('angularjs'),'',true);
```

I have angularjs listed as a dependency for ngRoute so Angular loads first. However, I still get the error that says it's not loading:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] 
>   **Description** This error occurs when a module
>   fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should
>   provide additional context.
>
> **Using ngRoute** In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to
>   its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x
>   or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.
>
> **Monkey-patching** Angular's ng module This error can also occur if you
>   have tried to add your own components to the ng module. This has never
>   been supported and from 1.3.0 it will actually trigger this error. For
>   instance the following code could trigger this error.
>
> angular.module('ng').filter('tel', function (){}); Instead create your
>   own module and add it as a dependency to your application's top-level
>   module. See #9692 and #7709 for more information

I only get the ngRoute error when I place `ng-app="myPlugin"` to a containing div.

When I check the output of my page I can verify that angularjs is loading first per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898348/angular-application-config-uncaught-object-error-ngroute).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keeping it simple? I usually declare my scripts in `functions.php` like this:

```
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'angularjs',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/angular.min.js'
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'angularjs-route',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/angular-route.min.js'
    );
```